# Why do different realists offer different explanations of reality

Tags: reality

"we have to be realistic", is often heard. Easily said. That normally means, realistic wrt to the view on the reality of the one who utters the expression. Different people have different views on reality. How come? Why different realists have different realities if reality is supposed to be independent of us human beings? Is reality simply dependent on us human beings? Buut in that case it's not a reality anymore in the sense that reality is independent of us human beings.

Comment: We have two related issues here: the assumption that reality is independent from human point of view and the assumption that human access to reality is "governed" by human points of view.

Comment: I think it might also be useful to think about the [is-ought problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is–ought_problem), often the statement "we have to be realistic" is made when making an argument about the best course of action in light of what the speaker thinks are the facts, not just about facts about reality in themselves. Even if everyone agrees about the goals and the comment is just about the most "reasonable" way to achieve them, this still may imply some kind of normative judgment about reasonableness, unless it can be reduced purely to a claim about probabilities of diff. outcomes.